# Is this the right site to ask about passive acoustic design in a building?

Tags: support, scope

I'm considering design ideas for a meeting place that would function (if somewhat less well) even without any electricity. (It would also likely be built with less sophisticated materials to maximize availability.) Crucial to this idea is that its construction would need to (mostly) passively serve two quite different acoustic profiles: one to maximize resonance to encourage unified group participation, and one to minimize echoes to allow one or a few speakers to be clearly heard.

Is this the right site to ask about a specific design idea that could enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic is perfectly acceptable. There have already been a couple of similar questions, so please search for those.  The existing answers may also help.